# Why am I not in the targeted group for my app?

Tags: android

I just uploaded my first app to the Android market. It contains ads from Admob, so I had to set target=android-13 in the project properties file.

In the manifest, I set

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="4"
android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

I also tried just

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

But in either case, the market tells me
"You're not in the targeted group for this item" with my Android 2.2 device.

Androids Developer Console says:
API level: 4-16+
Supported screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all

so, What are the right settings?

Comment: Same problem here. I have minSdkVersion="7" and targetSdkVersion="8" - also tried with just the minSdkVersion and no luck

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat as you. Just uploaded my app this evening and still showing that on all android devices. Possibly just Market Latency

Answer (score 1):

My problem was an initially published app would not show as compatible for any devices - the market website said "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."  And on the phone if you managed to open the app in the market it said "You're not in the targeted group for this item".  However, the developer console said it should be available on 943 devices.

I opened a ticket with Android support team ( https://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/request.py?contact_type=publishing ) and after a little back in forth with their automated systems, we got a response saying that they made some changes that may have resolved the problem.  I'm not sure if these were changes specific to our account, or if any account could have gotten the same error.
Before getting the email (while diligently troubleshooting), I had noticed that un-publishing and re-publishing the apk fixed the problem.

Conclusion: If anyone sees the problem where the developer console says the app is available on devices that the market is not allowing to install, try un-publishing and re-publishing your app (2 button clicks in the developer console) and if that doesn't work, open a ticket with google.